# Network not starting automatically

Tags: networking, debian, debian-wheezy

I just installed Debian 7.1 and configured a static IP address. But when I reboot and log-in, the network is not running. If I run `ifup eth0`, I get this message: *Stopping Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Daemon: avahi-daemon.* and then the network starts and works as expected. Why it doesn't start automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the interface set to start automatically at boot in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eth2
allow-hotplug eth2
iface eth2 inet dhcp
```

Comment: I had commented `allow-hotplug eth0` when adding `auto eth0`. Obviously I need both lines.